# Spark 1.5 as Client to a KAFKA 0.9 or 0.10

Tags: apache-spark, kafka-consumer-api

Can I write Spark 1.5 client using Kafka consumer API to get messages from KAFKA 0.9 or 0.10 and process them? 
If I can't then what would be the best way where Spark can be used as a processing engine to get messages and apply aggregation and statistical modeling to produce the final output.

Comment: is your kafka kerberosed?

Answer (score 1):

Please, find in official spark doc your answer..

This is an example of integration between spark and kafka in spark 1.5.2

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Thanks...it did not mention Apache KAFKA version. Secondly, If I do with Spark Streaming then initially where should I store messages before applying  my logic for aggregation and modelling?